# RobotFramework complaining consecutive whitespace issue

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide, robotframwork-whitelibrary

I am using robotframework 3.1.2 and its automatically parsing a txt file and complaining the error "**Collapsing consecutive whitespace during parsing is deprecated**" for every line in the file as the txt file has consecutive whitespaces all across the file.
I cannot cleanup the whitespaces in the file since its used by other team members.

How can I configure the robotframework to ignore the whitespaces or ignore that file?

I coudnt find any relevant help on google.
P.S: If I rename the file extension to something else other than txt( like .bin) robotframework stops complaining as it seems to be ignoring the file.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include an example of what you mean by "consecutive whitespace"?

Comment: Is the file a valid Robot Framework file? Then the warning will show. It is only a warning and safe to ignore. If other team members are using the file, then they all should have the spaces fixed, so the warnings do not appear (if the file still is valid). Please clarify if you are seeing those warnings on RIDE, because you only would see them when running tests on with Robot Framework. If only in RIDE, then don't open the Folder where the file is.